# Creating a vector of numbers based on letters

Tags: r

So, this is the question:

"Create a function that given one word, return the position
of word’s letters on letters vector. For example, if the word
is ‘abba’, the function will return 1 2 2 1."

What I have so far is this:

```
l <- function(word) {
    chr <- c()
    y <- c()
    strsplit(chr,word)
    i<-1
    while(i<length) {
           o<-letters[i]
           x<-chr[i]
           if(o==x) {
                    y[i]<-i
           }
           i+1
    }
    y
}
```

I have tried running l("hello") and it returns NULL. I'm very lost and would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: you're not assigning the output of `strsplit` to anything. also, your split argument is missing, should be `spit=""`

Answer (score 6):

With `base R`:

```
lapply(strsplit(x, "", fixed = TRUE), match, letters)

[[1]]
[1] 1 2 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I provide another interesting function in `base`:

```
x <- "abcxyz"
strtoi(strsplit(x, "")[[1]], 36) - 9
# [1]  1  2  3 24 25 26
```

`strtoi()` transforms the **base-n** numeral system into **base-10** (i.e. **decimal**) numeral system. Take **base-16** (i.e. **hexadecimal**) for example, `strtoi("12", base = 16)` will get `18` because 12 in hexadecimal is 18 in decimal. If base is 36, `strtoi()` will map **(1~9, a~z)** to **1~35**, namely, **a~z** in a **base-36** system is **10~35** in decimal. `-9` in my code will convert 10~35 to 1~26, which is what the OP requires. Another common use is to transform **binary** number into decimal. E.g. `strtoi("01001", base = 2)` gets 9.

Comment: I'm looking at the docs for `strtoi` (never used it, seems cool), but could you explain where you get the 36 and 9 from and what they do here?

Comment: @camille I'm sorry for ignoring the explanation. I edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(purrr)
my_fun <- function(x) {
  x %>% 
    strsplit("") %>% 
    map(factor, levels = letters) %>% 
    map(as.numeric)
}


x <- c("abba", "hello")
my_fun(x)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 2 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1]  8  5 12 12 15
```

Here we use that factors are integers under the hood.

Let `str` be a character vector, e.g. `str <- c('a', 'b', 'b', 'a')`. When we run `factor(str, levels = letters)` we convert it to a factor with 26 levels: 'a', 'b', 'c', and so on. If we apply `as.integer` to it, `a` will become 1, because it's the first level, 'b' - 2 and so on.